# How to start a variable number of threads in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am searching for a way to start multiple threads whose exact number can only be determined at runtime. The threads are not dependent on each other, so it's a fire-and-forget kind of problem.

The threads do need some context which is stored as internal variables of a class (Foo). Some of these variables are references. The class also holds a method that should be executed as the thread function (bar).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a){
        std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        m_a = new int(a);
    }

    ~Foo(){
        std::cout << "Destroyed" << std::endl;
        delete m_a;
    }

    void bar() {
        std::cout << "Internal var: " << *m_a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int* m_a;
};

int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::thread t(&Foo::bar, std::ref(Foo(i)));
        // the threads will be joined at a later point, this is for demo purposes
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error at this point:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = Foo]’
```

I get it that this error is caused because of the temporary nature of the object created in the for-loop. But if I remove the std::ref function, I get a segfault: `double free or corruption (fasttop)`

I am sure that there must be a way of doing this, but I am unaware of that. I would expect some output like (probably in this order, but not guaranteed):

```
Created
Internal var: 0
Destroyed

Created
Internal var: 1
Destroyed

...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Foo violates the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Why not just `std::thread t(&Foo::bar, Foo(i));`?  What is your purpose for using `std::ref`?

Comment: This looks like a variation of the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). What exactly are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: in general you need object with reference counting. addref on object, before pass it to thread, release, after stop use it in thread. delete when ref count became 0

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` would provide such refcounting.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** `Foo` is missing a copy/move constructor. See [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Add a copy constructor:

```
    Foo(Foo const& that) : m_a(new int(*that.m_a)) {}
```

And/or a move constructor:

```
    Foo(Foo && that) : m_a(that.m_a) { that.m_a = nullptr; }
```

**Problem 2:** `Foo(i)` is a temporary instance of `Foo`, it lives until the end of the full-expression (the `;`).

```
std::thread t(&Foo::bar, std::ref(Foo(i)));
//                                        ^
//                                        Foo(i) is dead at this point while the thread is starting!
```

You want it to live longer than that, in order to be usable inside the thread.

For example, like this (also answers your question about creating threads in a loop):

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> inputs;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        inputs.emplace_back(i);
        threads.emplace_back(&Foo::bar, &inputs.back());
    }
    
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Note: `std::ref(Foo(i))` doesn't compile because it has protection against returning references to temporaries (precisely to prevent issues like these).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimaly fixed version of your code:

- it includes the move ctor for Foo class (and explicitely deletes copy ctor)
- it moves the threads into a vector
- it joins the threads

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a) {
        std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        m_a = new int(a);
    }

    ~Foo() {
        if (m_a != NULL) {
            std::cout << "Destroyed" << std::endl;
            delete m_a;
        }
    }

    Foo(const Foo& other) = delete; //not used here

    Foo(Foo&& other) {
        std::cout << "Move ctor" << '\n';
        m_a = other.m_a;
        other.m_a = nullptr;
    }

    void bar() {
        std::cout << "Internal var: " << *m_a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int* m_a;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::thread t(&Foo::bar, Foo(i));
        vec.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    for (auto& t : vec) {
        t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The chief design failure seems that `t` is a variable inside the loop. That means it's destroyed at the end of each iteration - you never have 5 `std::thread` instances at the same time. Also, you fail to call `join` on those threads.

The `std::ref` apparently hides this problem and replaces it with another problem, but your original thread creation was correct: `std::thread t(&Foo::bar, Foo(i))`.

You probably want a `std::list<std::thread>`, and use `std::list::emplace_back` to create a variable amount. `std::list<std::thread>` allows you to remove threads in any order from the list.